# Return a constant string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I created a `string[]` getter to get some information on a class. I want it to always return the same value, and not create a new object on each call.

I have it implemented now like this:

```
string[] _someStrings = { "foo", "bar" };
protected string[] someStrings {
    get {
        return _someStrings;
    }
}
```

which seem to be OK. However, my first inkling was to write it like this:

```
protected string[] someStrings {
    get {
        return { "foo", "bar" };
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work (I get the error `; expected`).

Why?

(this is mainly a "getting-to-understand-C# question).

**update** I made a typo. I do **not** want to create a new object on each call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax would be this:

```
return new [] { "foo", "bar" };
```

The reason is that the short syntax without `new []` is only valid for an assignment.

As you correctly note in a comment, this will create a new object on every call. The only way to avoid this is with a field that stores the created instance and return that field. This is exactly the solution you already have.
Please note however, that this allows consumers to change the contents of the array and affect other consumers:

```
var a1 = foo.SomeStrings;
var a2 = foo.SomeStrings;
a1[0] = "Some other value";
Assert.Equal("Some other value", a2[0]); // will pass
```

Comment: Wouldnt that make a list of anonymous type? Shouldn't you write "new string[]"? (I believe you, but I'm trying to understand why...)

Comment: @Pluc: No, that creates an array. An anonymous type is created with `new { ... }` - note the missing square brackets. It looks similar but is something else completely. `new [] { "foo", "bar" };` and `new string[] { "foo", "bar" };` are exactly the same. In the first scenario, the compiler infers the element type of the array to be `string` because all the elements you specified are strings.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate approach, may I suggest, if the contents are supposed to be constant, using [a read-only collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) instead, such that:

```
private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> UnderlyingReadOnlyStrings;

// populate the read-only collection, then...

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ReadOnlyStrings {
  get { return UnderlyingReadOnlyStrings; }
}
```

The benefit here is that your collection truly is read-only. And practically constant. It can't be re-assigned to, and the contents cannot be altered. You could even declare the underlying collection as static and populate in a static constructor.

Your second example doesn't work, as previously explained, because you're trying to return an "inline array", so to speak, and the syntax is not correct, and if it were, you would be `new`ing the array each time - which goes against your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
protected string[] someStrings 
{
    get 
    {
        return new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
    }
}
```

You can't have `const` array, but you can have a `readonly` one that will work as you expect (can also be `static`, obviously):

```
public readonly string[] someStrings = { "foo", "bar" };
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a new object on each call? I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @BartFriederichs you said *"return the same value, and create a new object on each call"*

Comment: Creating a string array is really not that terrible. There is a better solution for "const" arrays. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Trickery in your updated answer you do what I do in my parameter, together with `readonly`. I want it in a property, for subclassing reasons (all subclasses should register a different set).

Comment: Even the `readonly` here can be misleading. Better to use a `ReadOnlyCollection` in cases where the collection itself and the items should be read-only. See my answer @BartFriederichs

Comment: If you need a different value set per inherited class, I'd have the property return a private collection defined on that class. @GrantThomas 's answer is what you'd need.